# What is the proper way of communicating between components in react? Why not using refs everywhere?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, ref

I know this subject is asked many times, but so far I couldn't find a reasonable answer.

If I want to make an app, that has two components: buttons and a timer that displays the time. When a button is clicked then the timer starts/pauses/resets. For me as a beginner in React, the obvious way of doing it is to create start() pause() reset() methods inside the timer and then once button is clicked to invoke this function (using refs).

But according to React doc and all the tutorials, this should be avoided. It should be that start() pause() reset() methods are kept in the most top component (parent of "buttons" and "timer" components), and from there they should control the timer.

But what in case I want to have 10 different timers (same component different design)? Wouldn't it be DRY coding to have start, pause, reset methods defined inside the timer, so the top component doesn't have 30 methods?

This is a hipotetical example, please don't give me workarounds, I'd like to understand reason of having ALL the logic in the top component, making the child components non reuseable as standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in my point of view you dont have to have the timer methods in any top component, timer must only know button has been clicked, in which case you pass down the click event to timer through props, that is to assume timer and button are rendered inside the same function. That means no refs either. When timer component receives new props it will re render.

The same will work for multiple timers inside a timers component.

Comment: Yes,this sounds reasonable: I pass the click event to timer. So I create a prop value let's say boolean, and in the timer inside componentDidUpdate() I check if this boolean has changed (to true or false, doesn't matter - the change is important). Thank you, this makes sense. But this way of coding looks much complicated than using refs, and it's not really intuitive, I mean React could have some better solution of handling the events.

Answer (score -1):

Given your example the point of moving the implementation "up" on the layers would be to be able to use the same timer component in different parts of your app where maybe the start() should behave differently each time.
The component itself would have no way to know what each specific "start" event should do, since the component should not have any knowledge of how it is been used at any time.

Think of the callbacks as event handlers, where the caller passes down what should be done when an event occurs

This actually enforces DRY, since you need 1 timer ( the logic of start,pause,stop,"timer reached" maybe etc) and then each caller hooks up what he wants to do when those events occur.

If you think of the structure of React itself, and its life cycle event, its the same thing. "ComponentDidMount" is no different than you timer's "start" for example, just a different context. The concept thought is the same

EDIT: It is important to think about what stays fixed in your component for everyone and what should be configurable.
Your timer for example will always tick once per second, right? So the time tracking part will always be constant for your app, it should reside within the component. The component should have a Start,Pause,Stop set of methods defined in it, since stop will always just stop the count, start will always resume it. 
But you will need to expose an OnStart,OnStop,OnPause, so that callers can hook the logic they need using your timer. I dont know if i can explain this well enough...

EDIT 2:
For example check below for the Start method of the timer:

```
 function Start(){
    // set the interval here or wtver way you will have to measure ticks
// ...
// ...
    if(this.props.OnStart)
     this.props.OnStart();
    }
```

Now ofcourse the callers will not be responsible for implementing the actual ticking ( allthough one day someone may come and request a tracker that is relative to someone travelling the speed of light or something, so the ticking can also be configurable...), but if they do need to have a hook on the start event, and they will, then you can implement it this way.
What the callback function does is not known to the component ( business logic moved up) but the common-to-all 'tick once per second' now is no concern to the callers

EDIT 3:
Ok so.. if the button is clicked we will start the timer and then call any hooks given by the props

```
 function OnEveryClick(){
    // here you will write anything you want your component to do every time the button is clicked, regardless of who is the caller, like our previous Start method
this.Start();
    }

function ButtonClicked(){
// first you call your method every time
 this.OnEveryClick();
// then if the caller also wants to do some stuff, you evaluate their function aswell
  if(this.props.OnSubmit)
    this.props.OnSubmit();
}
```

Then on the render you do something like this

```
<button onClick={this.ButtonClicked.bind(this)}>
```

Comment: "point would be to be able to use the same timer component in different parts of your app" -  when I want to have two timers, then on the top level I need to modify the function that counts the time for each timer separately. But if the timing function would be inside the timer then I can reuse the timer again just by copying. If I put all the logic in top, then the timer component that suposed to display the time is totaly useless to copy it, as it's logic is in the main component of the app.

Comment: Oh no man, you need to seperate the "logical" parts and the "specific business" parts.
That means that the "count the time" function should be within the component, because it does not change! Time will always go by in the same speed for us, so there is no point moving this part of the component upwards. But you should have an OnStart for example that callers will be able to hook their own methods

Comment: "But you will need to expose an OnStart,OnStop,OnPause" -> thanks, so the only question is how do you do this? Refs give you access to those methods. Or you do it as suggested in salomari87's answer, by passing a prop to the timer and then waiting in the timer for this prop to change?

Comment: Ok thx, but the question is how the timer knows to start ticking? How to you fire this ticking inside timer?

Comment: Ok now I see "your problem", the thing is that the timer component is paralell to the button, so then your this.start() has to tell the timer component to run it's start() method and start ticking. In my idea button and timer are both child components. You'd have to use ref right?